# Override superclass delegate with sub-protocol Swift

Tags: ios, swift, types, delegates, overriding

This is my implementation of a certain class:

```
public class JABTouchableView {
     public var delegate: JABTouchableViewDelegate?
}

public protocol JABTouchableViewDelegate {
     func someFunction ()
}
```

Now I am trying to write a subclass:

```
public class JABButton: JABTouchableView {
     override public var delegate: JABButtonDelegate?
}

public protocol JABButtonDelegate: JABTouchableViewDelegate {
     func someNewFunction ()
}
```

But I get the error "property delegate with type JABButtonDelegate? cannot override a property with type JABTouchableViewDelegate?"

I thought I did everything right, but clearly not. Can someone explain the problem to me?

Answer (score 0):

because can not override variable with different data types.

Comment: I know, but the data type I am overriding with inherits from the one it wants